# При наведении мыши изменить картинку вместе с другими

Tags: javascript

[image: пример]

**Есть 10 изображений. 
На странице видны только 3.** 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на одно изображение, оно менялось,а в вместе с ним менялись другие. (как показано на прикреплённой картинке). Причем, чтобы они менялись не хаотично,а по определенному порядку. Т.е. при наведении на вторую картинку, всегда должна отображаться комбинация "CEK".

Comment: не очень понятна логика. Что видно, что не видно... Что на что меняется при наведении куда... По-подробней, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно каждому элементу(div/img) добавить событие [mouseenter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp) которое будет вызывать метод (и передавать индекс элемента), метод который будет изменять картинки в зависимости от индекса.

html

```
<div onmouseout="Replace(0)">
    <img onmouseenter="Replace(1)" id="img1" src="A.jpeg" alt="Index 1">
    <img onmouseenter="Replace(2)" id="img2" src="D.jpeg" alt="Index 2">
    <img onmouseenter="Replace(3)" id="img3" src="H.jpeg" alt="Index 3">
</div>
```

js (jquery)

```
var Replace = function(ind) {
   switch(ind) {
      case 0:
         $('#img1').attr('src', 'A.jpeg');
         $('#img2').attr('src', 'D.jpeg');
         $('#img3').attr('src', 'H.jpeg');
         break;
      case 1:
         $('#img1').attr('src', 'B.jpeg');
         $('#img2').attr('src', 'F.jpeg');
         $('#img3').attr('src', 'K.jpeg');
         break;
      case 2:
         $('#img1').attr('src', 'C.jpeg');
         $('#img2').attr('src', 'E.jpeg');
         $('#img3').attr('src', 'K.jpeg');
         break;
      case 3:
         ...
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! Это именно то, что надо! Только как сделать, чтобы при отведении мыши от любой картинки, все они вернулись в первое  положение?

Comment: @DmitryLevkovsky атрибут "onmouseout", который пусть передает в функцию 0. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо!  .......